# How do I get the TeamCity Duplicates Finder to report the absolute path to a file, not the relative path?

Tags: teamcity

I created a TeamCity (6.5.3 - build 17985) build with a Duplicate Finder step. This build works correctly however in the build report, I got the message:

> "File not found: "../../../../createTagBuild/createTagBuild/SQLScript.cs"

**Is it possible see the fully resolved file path (like "c:\blah\blah\blah\SQLScript.cs")?**

Comment: you should try the team city forums. Good luck.

Comment: Gabriel, please post issue to our tracker (http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/TW) about this defect. I will take a look.

Comment: Posted (http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-18550?projectKey=TW) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Update TeamCity to Version 6.5.5 (build 18087), the Duplicate finder stopted work. So looking for some answer I found in this [link - YouTrack from jetbrains](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-18784) one patch to fix it.

After fix it I have had the same original probleme from this question.

> "File not found: "../../../../createTagBuild/createTagBuild/SQLScript.cs"

So I decided to try some workaround, and I found the solution.

In my Build Step Configuration at "Version Control Settings", in the Checkout Settings group, the option Checkout Directory is empty, so I decided set the same PATH from build Step that is responsable from the Checkout/Update.

After I set the path the follow msg is displayed:

> The following build configurations have the same checkout directory but different VCS settings, this may lead to unnecessary clean checkout on agent:

So I just ignore because the option VCS checkout Model is "Do not checkout files automatically"

Now is working correctly !!!